# Best way to manipulate pages while embedding Webkit?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, dom, webkit

I'm using Webkit-sharp to embed Webkit into an application and I need to hook certain links to perform actions in my app rather than their normal action.

I've considered using Javascript to iterate over the anchor tags and replace the ones that match with the proper link, but I'm wondering if this is the best way.  Is there a preferred way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has a lot of useful iteration features that may be able to use for that. :-) I haven't used jQuery, but [`find`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find) and [`attr`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr) look promising for your purposes.